# Check if m3u8 playlist is available with cURL

Tags: php, html, curl, m3u8

I've a cURL script that i was used all the time to check if a m3u8 file exist on te server, so yes then play the mp4 file, so no then let see a picture offline.

But since yesterday the script is not working anymore. I checked if the m3u8 file exist with curl, and then on the http code 200. Is there another way to check if the m3u8 file exist on the server?

```
<?php


function url_test( $url ) {
  $timeout = 10;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
  $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_respond = trim( strip_tags( $http_respond ) );
  $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
  if ( ( $http_code == "200" ) || ( $http_code == "302" ) ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // return $http_code;, possible too
    return false;
  }
  curl_close( $ch );
}

$website = "***.m3u8";
if( !url_test( $website ) ) {
  echo $website ." is down!";
}
else { echo $website ." functions correctly."; }
?>
```

Why this is not working anymore? cURL says that the file is not at the server but i can download it with my laptop on the same link.

Who can help?

Thanks.

Marv

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser, press F12 and then select the "Network" tab in the box that just opened when pressing F12. Then paste the m3u8 url in the browser address bar and hit enter. The request must show up in the requests list in the Network section. Click on the request and see the HTTP status code that you have received from the server; it may be another one than 200 or 302 (the cases you are covering in your script).

I would also add:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: That's the problem. It's going directly download, so i dont get a http status code on my laptop.

Comment: also, add this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Comment: i did, still it says it's offline.

Comment: in order to download that file, you are initialising a HTTP request, so you receive a status code, even-though you'll not see some html on your screen and the download will be started right away. try following my steps and you'll se you get a status code.

Comment: or just use var_dump($http_code); and see what code are you getting in your php script.